# Strange React hooks behavior, can't access new state from a function

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, antd, react-hooks

I use the library [`react-use-modal`](https://github.com/wowlusitong/react-use-modal/blob/master/README-en.md), and
I'm trying to read the updated value of `confirmLoading` when inside the `handleClick` function.

`handleClick` does read the first value of `confirmLoading` defined when doing `const [ confirmLoading, setConfirmLoading ] = useState(false)`, but never updates when I `setConfirmLoading` inside `handleOk`.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

```
import { Button, Modal as ModalAntd } from 'antd'
import { useModal } from 'react-use-modal'

export interface ModalFormProps {
    form: React.ReactElement
}

export const ModalForm: React.FC = () => {
    const [ confirmLoading, setConfirmLoading ] = useState(false)
    const { showModal, closeModal } = useModal()

    const handleOk = () => {
        setConfirmLoading(true)
        setTimeout(() => {
            setConfirmLoading(false)
            closeModal()
        }, 1000)
    }

    const handleCancel = () => {
        closeModal()
    }

    const handleClick = () => {             
        showModal(({ show }) => (
            <ModalAntd                  
                onCancel={handleCancel}
                onOk={handleOk}
                title='Title'
                visible={show}
            >
                //  the value of confirmLoading is always the one defined 
                //  with useState at the beginning of the file.
                <p>{confirmLoading ? 'yes' : 'no'}</p>                  
            </ModalAntd>
        ))
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={handleClick}>
                Open Modal
            </Button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because of closures. The component that you pass to `showModal` remembers `confirmLoading` and when you call function `setConfirmLoading` your component renders again and function `handleClick` is recreated. 'Old' `handleClick` and 'old' component in `showModal` know nothing about the new value in `confirmLoading`.

Try to do this:

```
export const ModalForm: React.FC = () => {
    const { showModal, closeModal } = useModal();

    const handleClick = () => {

        showModal(({ show }) => {
            const [ confirmLoading, setConfirmLoading ] = useState(false);
            const handleOk = () => {
                setConfirmLoading(true)
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setConfirmLoading(false)
                    closeModal()
                }, 1000)
            };

            const handleCancel = () => {
                closeModal()
            };

            return (
                <ModalAntd
                    onCancel={handleCancel}
                    onOk={handleOk}
                    title='Title'
                    visible={show}
                >
                    // the value of confirmLoading is always the one defined
                    // with useState at the beginning of the file.
                    <p>{confirmLoading ? 'yes' : 'no'}</p>
                </ModalAntd>
            );
        })
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={handleClick}>
                Open Modal
            </Button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrii. I knew there was something due to `closures`, yet everytime I modified the code, I ended up using the `hooks` the wrong way, with a `you can't use hooks there` message. Your solution works perfectly!